# Rationale behind member function swap

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, swap, generic-programming

In the standard library, if a class type has a specialized swap algorithm, then it will have a member function `swap` and a free function `swap` that simply forwards to the member function. I don't quite get the rationale behind having both of them (and thus code duplication) but not just the free function one. Note that, when I say the free function, I take to mean the specialized free swap function, not the generic `std::swap` function template. Such a specialized function may have privileged access to the relevant class by being a friend of it.

I have two points to support just leaving the free function rather than the member function. First, it forms a more generic swap interface to facilitate writing generic algorithms, for non-class types like arrays cannot have member functions. Second, swap is a binary operation involving two operands and demonstrates a sense of symmetry. It's more natural and intuitive to perform swap using a free function that does not have bias on either operand. For this reason, I have always felt somewhat weird when using the member function `swap` as if I was performing some operation that is based on the invoking object.

Answer (score 3):

The free function cannot see the private guts of the class, so the actual functionality needs to be provided as a class member. However, you want the free function because it's a customization point (using ADL); so a generic algorithm will call the free `swap` in order to achieve whatever swapping is appropriate for the type at hand.

The member function is also useful for constructions like `T().swap(existing_thing)`, since the free function requires lvalue arguments.

I suppose the alternative would have been to make `swap` a public friend function declared inside the class, which could be found via ADL just as well.

Comment: The specialized free swap function may have privileged access to the class by declaring it as a friend. Besides, I don't see the usefulness of constructions like `T().swap(existing_thing)` when you can simply and more readably clear `existing_thing`.

Comment: @Lingxi: Clearing holds on to the allocation; swapping with an empty thing does not.

Comment: If such usage is to be supported, one can just design the specialized free function to take a universal reference type.